# CSS transitions efficiency: Group vs individuals

Tags: jquery

I have this page

```
<div id ="main">
  <div class="T" id="fourty"></div>
  <div class="T" id="willto"></div>
  <div class="T" id="next"></div>
  <div class="T" id="update"></div>
  <div class="T" id="seven"></div>
</div>
```

And I need to apply CSS filter blur with JQuery. Which one would be more resources efficient?

```
$("#main").css({"filter":"blur(10px)"});
```

or

```
$(".T").css({"filter":"blur(10px)"});
```

What I found that the second example adds the filter property to each one of the elements in this class. So I thought it might be heavier because it executes it on a per element base so it takes the filter time x the elements count, but I'm not sure about this theory anyone can confirm or deny it?

Comment: Why not experiment and find out?

Comment: Use the first one if performance matter